# ERRO: query_engine-windows.dll.node

Tags: node-modules, prisma

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHycb.png)
In Portuguese: Tentei executar esse comando no terminal -> npx prisma generate, mas esse erro aconteceu!

```
In English: Tried running this command in terminal -> npx prisma generate, but this error happened!
```

In Portuguese: Tentei criar um arquivo .svg com um ERD(Diagrama de entidade relacionamento), era para esse arquivo aparecer na pasta prisma

In English: I tried to create a .svg file with an ERD (Entity Relationship Diagram), this file was supposed to appear in the prism folder

Answer (score 1):

Installing prisma client with: `yarn add @prisma/client` should fix this issue for you.

For Reference here's a GitHub Issue: [#9184](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/9184) which discusses the same error that you are facing. There are several workarounds mentioned which fixed the error for the users.

Answer (score -1):

So, my issue was resolved when I deleted the file `query_engine-windows.dll.node` that was located within the `/node_modules/.prisma/query_engine-windows.dll.node` folder.